# add a scanned handwritten signature to an annotated PDF

Tags: pdf, annotation

How can I edit a PDF and also add my handwritten signature image which I have available as .gif, .jpg, or .xcf.

I tried `flpsed` which is good for annotating PDF files but it does not seem to allow the importing of my handwritten signature image.  I also tried the Oracle `PDF Extension` for Open Office on my Libre Office.  The intention was to export as a PDF once the document was finalized.  It complains that I don't have the password to open the PDF.  This is unexpected since `flpsed` and `calibre` do not ask for a password.

I also tried `calibre` to convert the PDF to RTF, for the purpose of editing or annotating the RTF with Open Office.  The intention was to export as a PDF once done. Unfortunately, `calibre` did a very poor job of the conversion, leaving out the grid lines which are essential in many corporate or government forms.

`Xournal` was tried.  It does not seem to have an "import image" type of feature.  When I used the clipboard to paste an image, nothing happened.  (Gimp's copy to clipboard was the source used in this attempt.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/#get) might work for you. It's free but has a slight watermark on saving. It has an Ubuntu 14 version that works in 16+. This is the insert menu:

[image]

Comment: It looks like that application is no longer in the store